# How to get the process name iisexpress instead of dotnet in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I am learning asp.net core when executing in browser i am getting response header has kestrel instead of iisexpress. I wrote the following code in Startup.cs configure method to get the process name but i'm still getting dotnet i'm not able to get iisexpress.

```
app.Run(async (context) => {
  await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!\n");
  await context.Response.WriteAsync(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);//dotnet             
});
```

In Program.cs I add .UseIIS()

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) => 
  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseIIS()
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Following is from .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
<RootNamespace>CookieStore</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Kindly help me to run the project both in InProcess and OutOfProcess.

Comment: "i'm not able to get iisexpress":  But I get `iisexpress` when I run it with Visual Studio (ASP.NET Core 2.2). Is there a demo that reproduces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally today the issue got resolved, after I updated my Visual Studio 2017. Earlier I used VS2017 15.3 after the update to VS2017 15.9, the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the application from the CLI using "dotnet run" it will run in kestrel by default, if you are using Visual Studio try running the application with the IIS Express from launch drop down.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 in windows 10 Home edition, but still I got dotnet only.

Comment: Make sure your launchsettings.json have an entry for IISExpress

Comment: My launchSettings.json is IISExpress.  Check the following code.<br/> `"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }`